# Should you zip files when saving blobs to SQL?

Tags: json, sql-server, t-sql, zip

I have JSON file that I want to save as a blob to Microsoft SQL Server.

The pros for zipping is saving space, the cons is the readability that getting lost.

I want to know if T-SQL has any optimization in which it zips the blobs on its own. I know that columnar databases work this way, like Vertica or Postgres for example.

Comment: Don't zip this... Space is not expensive, but CPU time is...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I personally would not compress them if I wanted to be able to search by them.  I do not believe it compresses a blob on it's own.  I know for a fact even just very large `VARCHAR` columns do not compress on their own, so I would not expect a blob to.  However there is built in compression you can turn on:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2015/12/08/built-in-functions-for-compressiondecompression-in-sql-server-2016/

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/data-compression/enable-compression-on-a-table-or-index?view=sql-server-2017

There are some advantages to it but usually at the cost of CPU.  So if I were you, I'd probably not zip up the files to put in SQL, but I might compress the tables I store.  It would depend on exactly what the data was, json probably gets a lot of space back on compression, but a .jpeg would not.

An option I have done in the past is to simply store my files on a content server somewhere, and store in SQL the meta data about the file (name, tags, patch to where I stored it, file extension, etc.)  That way my data is easy to get at/put there and I simply use SQL to look it up.  Additionally it has allowed me when it was large text files to also use `Lucene` indexes from `solr` to make a full text searchable solution since the data wasn't stuffed into a SQL table.  Just an idea! :)

One more thought, if I were to store big json files into SQL I would probably choose `VARCHAR(MAX)` or `NVARCHAR(MAX)` as my datatype.  Anytime I have tried to use `TEXT`, `IMAGE`, etc. I would later run into some kind of SQL error if I tried to do a tricky query.  I believe Microsoft is trying to use `VARCHAR(MAX)` to replace the `blob` type of data types and is slowly deprecating them.

Comment: `NTEXT`, `TEXT` and `IMAGE` are [deprecated officially](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). For JSON you should use `NVARCHAR(MAX)`